# Eclipse - Adding/Removing Projects to Server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ant, automated-deploy

is there a way to automate (ant/maven) the eclipse menu function to add/remove a project to a server?

**Scenario**:
I'm using eclipse to develop a large Liferay project with multiple modules. The deployment process is rather large. I have to manually drag & drop those modules onto the running server in a certain order.

I'd like to simply call an ant task for that.

**Note**:
I'm not talking about simple hot deployment. I need those modules added to the server with eclipse "knowing" about it. So whenever I change some code, the module gets redeployed on the fly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using the eclipse liferay plugin  ? https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/liferay-ide

Comment: Yes, I'm using the liferay plugin. This way, I can add the modules with drag & drop and get excately what I need. But I want to automate this.